# How Can I Track All Pages Of A Domain?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I track all pages of a domain using JavaScript in index.php.

Like ga.js by Google.

I want to input some script in index.php in some site and through that script I can track all pages from that site

Like `<script src="www.mysite.com/some.js">` in www.other.com's index.php and I wish to track `www.other.com/<all>.php`

Comment: Javascript is not (executed in) PHP.

Comment: I know that. I want to implement the same functionality of ga.js by google. Is it possible ? Or how they made it possible to track all page visit by Including js only in index.php ?

Comment: Because index.php is used in generating all pages. ga.js only tracks pages in which it is loaded. It's not magical.

Comment: Ok its clear now. Thanks All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track page stats you have to have scripting for every page delivered and update the stats on a database; or you need a plugin module on the server, that can give you a lot more detail.  Most hosting services have some form of this kind of tracking already installed.

The Google analytics requires a client side script on every page because the stats on maintained on the Google servers.  The only page you can track from index.php is index.php

Comment: No, he's saying that whoever owns the site has to find a way to put the js on every page